# How use VisualVM profiler with STS?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, visualvm, jvisualvm

I would like to use VisualVM profiler with Springsource Tool Suite (STS).
The application is running under the Tomcat server in STS.
When jvisualvm.exe is run from the jdk bin folder, the following error is displayed:

Local Java applications cannot be detected.....

Would you know how I can correct this?

Thank you,
S..

Answer (score 0):

A google search for the error led me here: http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html

It says this:

> Description: An error dialog saying that local applications cannot be detected is shown immediately 
>   after VisualVM startup.
>
> Resolution:  This can happen on Windows systems, it's caused by misconfigured jvmstat technology used to > detect the running applications. There are two possible causes:
>
> - Insufficient permissions for %TMP%\hsperfdata_username folder - make sure you're able to create a file in the directory and eventually update the permissions for full folder access. Alternatively you can just re-create the folder which should automatically set the correct access rights. See see this forums.sun.com thread for more details.
> - Having %TMP%\hsperfdata_username folder on a FAT disk - by default jvmstat doesn't work on FAT disks due to security restrictions. You can bypass the security check by setting the -XX:+PerfBypassFileSystemCheck flag for both VisualVM and the monitored application. See the JDK bug #5042659 for more details.

Not sure if that helps. But it seems to describe your problem and a suggested resolution.